# What diagnostics can I collect with MariaDB Connector/C upon an error?

Tags: sql, c, mariadb, mysql-connector

I would like to collect as many diagnostics as reasonable and possible when getting an error upon running a query to MariaDB/MySQL via Connector/C.
So far I am collecting `mysql_errno()` and `mysql_error()`. What else can I reasonably collect? (I.e. without dumping the whole database to a file, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would collect anything that allows to reproduce the error:

- the SQL query (if prepared statement with bound data values)
- the database user
- the database name
- the database connection string (hostname, port number)
- possibly session variables modified in the current session
- the OS user
- the OS machine
- version of MySQL client.